# Assessing the accuracy of a particular A/B testing design methodology

Tags: inference, experiment-design, causality, ab-test

I commented to a colleague that we could improve our measurement of treatment effects by ensuring proper randomisation into treatment and control groups by balancing the treatment and control groups on variables we thought could influence the propensity to take the action we are trying to measure.

His response was that we could test whether this offers an improvement in accuracy by taking our population of treated individuals, splitting them into 2 groups and measuring the difference in outcome between these 2 treated groups. If the difference in outcome is near 0, then we have evidence that the current methodology is already controlling any confounding/bias.

Is this a correct line of thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a group, randomly split it in half, and compare the outcomes in the two halves, the difference will always be near zero, so this does nothing to enhance the claim of no confounding. The control group could still be radically different from the treated group (i.e., indicating severe confounding in your study).

*Edit to respond to comments:*

Let $S \in{1, 2}$ be an indicator for the splitting variable in the treated group that is being used to create the two subsets of the treated group that are going to be compared. If this splitting is random, then it is independent from the outcome, i.e., $Y \perp S |T = 1$. So, $E[Y|S=1,T=1] = E[Y|S=2,T=1]$. That is, the means of the outcomes in the two splits of the treatment groups will always be equal (in expectation) regardless of whether there is confounding between the treated and control groups. You learn nothing about the control group by randomly splitting the treated group.

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for your answer. Can I ask you to please elaborate on why the difference will always be near zero when randomly splitting a group?

Comment: @AaronGibney The two groups come from the same population, and so their expected outcome is going to be the same.  Assuming the outcome doesn't have some pathological distribution (e.g. is very long tailed) then we should (erroneously) detect that there is a difference a proportion $\alpha$ of the time.

Comment: Demetri, thanks for your reply. Would you perhaps detail 'The two groups come from the same population, and so their expected outcome is going to be the same' formally? I think it would help me get the intuition.

Comment: I edited my reply. The idea that randomly splitting a group will always yield similar distributions in the splits is so fundamental that is is hard to explain intuitively if that statement alone does not provide enough enough intuition to understand it. Not sure formalizing it will really help.

Comment: Noah, thanks a lot. Am I right that this is a case of the law of large numbers? If we have a group and split it into 2, the law of large numbers tells us that the expectation of the sample mean(s) approaches the population mean as n increases...? Therefore both sample means are approaching the same number and their difference is always near 0. I think this is what you mean by fundamental...?

Comment: I assume that no reply means yes to the above :).